# "Application requires that assembly *** be installed" error while trying to install my ClickOnce app

Tags: c#, winforms, dll, clickonce

Here's an error I get when I try to install my application from the publish location:

[image]

I have my application (and a DLL used by it) linked to version 1.61.4111... of QWhale.Common which is a 3rd party DLL. I have been used this version since about 4 updates ago and never had this problem. I have no idea which part of my application or DLL could be trying to link to the older version. The only thing I did different on this version is that I moved my application's project folders to a new location in my computer.

Where should I start trying to find where this problem is coming from? Did you ever have this problem before?

Comment: Perhaps some license file in the solution still has the old version number in it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Yahia commented, this can be a licensing issue but if you've been using this assembly for a while and if you've been compiling it with your application, there is a chance that a setting associated with the file could have changed with your projects settings.

Assuming you are using Visual Studio, I recommend opening your Projects properties window and navigating to the Publish tab and opening the Application Files Dialog.

From there, find the referenced, 3rd party assemblies make try setting the `Publish Status` to `Include` and the `DownloadGroup` to `(Required)`.

Save your changes and republish your application.